# Why is APEX_COLLECTION.AddMember only adding the last index called of the outer loop, overwriting the previous indices?

Tags: sql, plsql, collections, oracle-apex, apex

I have an procedure that I am calling on APEX. The procedure has two parameters. The status is 'Operational'. Here is sample data for the i_schoolList clob parameter. It splits the data into the l_schoolNames table type:

```
Harmony
Crestview
Evergreen
Brightside
Summit
Willowbrook
Riverside
Valleyview
Oakridge
Meadowlark
```

Below is my procedure:

```
Procedure POPULATE_SCHOOLS(i_status     In Varchar2,
                           i_schoolList In Clob) Is
  
  -- Declare a collection type to store the split values
  TYPE schoolNameList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  -- Declare a variable to hold the split values
  l_schoolNames schoolNameList;
  l_count       Number;
  
  -- Declare variables for column values
  l_region       CLONE_FINAL.REGION%TYPE;
  l_schoolName     CLONE_FINAL.school_NAME%TYPE;
  l_sector       CLONE_FINAL.SECTOR%TYPE;

  --Declare variables for error logging
  l_errorNumber  Number;
  l_parameters   Varchar2(4000);
  l_errorMessage Varchar2(4000);
  l_procedure    Varchar2(400);
  l_owner        Varchar2(100);

  --Temporary variables
  l_proc_name  VARCHAR2(100);
  l_error_info VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_log_data   CLOB;
    
  Cursor schoolRows(schoolName In Varchar2)
  Is
    Select region, 
           school_name, 
           sector
    From   S_SCHOOLS
    Where  school_NAME = schoolName;
    
Begin
  -- Calculate the number of occurrences of the delimiter
  l_count := REGEXP_COUNT(i_schoolList, CHR(10)) + 1;

  -- Iterate over the occurrences and extract the substrings
  FOR ind IN 1..l_count LOOP
    l_schoolNames(ind) := REGEXP_SUBSTR(i_schoolList, '[^' || CHR(10) || ']+', 1, ind);
  END LOOP;

  IF apex_collection.collection_exists(p_collection_name => 'SCHOOLS') THEN
    apex_collection.delete_collection(p_collection_name => 'SCHOOLS');
  END IF;


  --Create collection
  apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection(p_collection_name => 'SCHOOLS');

  --Check if status is operational only. If it is, select from CLONE_FINAL table
  If (i_status = 'Operational')
  Then
    l_errorMessage := 'i.Count=' || l_schoolNames.Count        || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                      'SQLERRM:'                             || CHR(13) || SQLERRM                || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                      'DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE:' || CHR(13) || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE;
                        
    insert_log_entry(l_proc_name, l_parameters, l_errorMessage);
    
    --Loop through SCHOOLS to get data
    For schoolIndex In 1..l_schoolNames.Count
    Loop
    
      l_errorMessage := 'schoolIndex='         || schoolIndex         || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                        'l_schoolNames.FIRST=' || l_schoolNames.FIRST || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                        'l_schoolNames.LAST='  || l_schoolNames.LAST  || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                        'l_schoolNames.COUNT=' || l_schoolNames.COUNT || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                        'SQLERRM:'                                || CHR(13) || SQLERRM                || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                        'DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE:'    || CHR(13) || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('schoolIndex=' || schoolIndex || ' l_schoolNames(schoolIndex)=' ||  l_schoolNames(schoolIndex));

      insert_log_entry(l_proc_name, l_parameters, l_errorMessage);

      For dataRec In schoolRows(schoolName => l_schoolNames(schoolIndex))
      Loop
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_schoolNames.Count=' || l_schoolNames.Count || ' schoolIndex=' ||  schoolIndex);

          l_errorMessage := 'schoolIndex='                           || schoolIndex                         || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                            'schoolRows(l_schoolNames(schoolIndex)='    || l_schoolNames(schoolIndex)            || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                            'SQLERRM:'                             || CHR(13) || SQLERRM                || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                            'DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE:' || CHR(13) || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE;
                        
          insert_log_entry(l_proc_name, l_parameters, l_errorMessage);
          --Add the school to the apex collection to display on the Front end page 10922:5
          apex_collection.add_member(p_collection_name => 'SCHOOLS',
                                     p_c001            => dataRec.region,
                                     p_c002            => dataRec.school_name,
                                     p_c003            => dataRec.sector);
      End Loop;
    End Loop;
  End If;
Exception
When Others
Then
  --Set error logging variables
  l_errorNumber  := 56032;

  l_parameters   := 'i_status='   || i_status   || CHR(13) ||
                    'i_schoolList=' || i_schoolList;

  l_errorMessage := 'Error getting schools for "Operational" status'                          || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                    'SQLERRM:'                             || CHR(13) || SQLERRM                             || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                    'DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE:' || CHR(13) || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE;

  l_procedure    := 'POPULATE_SCHOOLS';

  l_owner        := 'USER';
          
  l_errorMessage := 'ERROR IN EXCEPTION'                          || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                    'SQLERRM:'                             || CHR(13) || SQLERRM                || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
                    'DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE:' || CHR(13) || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE;
                        
  insert_log_entry(l_proc_name, l_parameters, l_errorMessage);
        --Log error in VODAERR table
        /*LOGGER.LOGERROR(ErrNum    => l_errorNumber, 
                        p_Param   => l_parameters,
                        p_ErrText => l_errorMessage,
                        p_PROC    => l_procedure,
                        p_OWNER   => l_owner);*/

End POPULATE_SCHOOLS;
```

I have checked the logs that I am logging in the code and can see that only the last index, in this case it is 10 in the example above, gets added to the apex collection. Suppose there are 3 or 4 rows returned in the second cursor, then it only adds the 3 or 4 rows in the last index of the first loop. It seems like it is overwriting the previous apex collection the whole time from the previous loop, because I can see that the index of the first loop gets incremented by looking at the logs. Does someone perhaps know why it is doing this and is this an oracle bug, because I tried using different kind of loops and nothing is working?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible case with the emp/dept sample dataset ? I'm happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are doing well.

This problem was fixed.

The problem with this one was that it did not like the CHR(13) and CHR(10) when doing the loop. It seems like if you split using those two, it does not split correctly and instead just takes the last index if you use CHR(10) and the first index if you use CHR(13). To resolve this issue, I replaced both CHR(10) and CHR(13) with a pipe "|" and then proceeded to split them. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Without having your code and data it's challenging to figure out what is going wrong. All I can advise is: instrument your code by adding debug statements. You could also use the add_member function instead of procedure to check what is happening. Here is an example:

```
DECLARE
  l_collection VARCHAR2(100) := 'EMP';
  l_seq NUMBER;
  l_rows NUMBER;
BEGIN
  APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_OR_TRUNCATE_COLLECTION(p_collection_name => l_collection);
  apex_debug.info(
    p_message => 'KL Debug: before LOOP');

  FOR r IN (SELECT ename FROM emp)
  LOOP
    apex_debug.info(
        p_message => 'KL Debug: in LOOP ename: %0',
        p0        => r.ename);
    l_seq := APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBER (
              p_collection_name => l_collection,
              p_c001 => r.ename);
    apex_debug.info(
        p_message => 'KL Debug: in LOOP collection seq: %0',
        p0        => l_seq);
    SELECT count(*) 
      INTO  l_rows 
      FROM apex_collections 
      WHERE collection_name = l_collection; 
    apex_debug.info(
        p_message => 'KL Debug: in LOOP collection rowcount: %0',
        p0        => l_rows);
  END LOOP;
  apex_debug.info(
    p_message => 'KL Debug: after LOOP');
END;
```

Then run the page in debug, check the request for which the process is fired and go through the logs:

[image]

Comment: Debugging using apex and debugging using logging into a table will bring back the same result as I explained above. I have tried a different solution where you split the Clob input parameter in a cursor and loop through that to do APEX_COLLECTION.AddMember in the loop and that also just took the last index of the cursor that split the rows. So say the where clause below picked up 3 records in its last index splitting, it will only populate those 3 those and nothing else.

```
WHERE SCHOOL_NAME IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(ATOLL_GLOBAL.SPLITSTR(i_schoolList, CHR(10)))
```

Comment: Also, I am using the apex collection to generate a classic report on APEX and then I want to use it afterwards to in a different process block to send though to another procedure. So the apex collection you see above is to generate the classic report and keep the collection there for future use. I have thought of using a temporary table and make a job to drop the temporary tables, but this is not user friendly as the users will just have their temp table they generated dropped after 1 minute or whatever.

Comment: My logging shows exactly what is happening. If, in an iteration of your loop, the apex collection is not updated, the rowcount will not change. For that case, what is the value of l_seq and l_rows in the debug ?

Comment: I have tested a sample of 6 records using the debugging you provided above. I can see in the apex logs that the rowcount is logged 5 times as 0 in the apex collection before it hits the 6th index. Upon hitting the 6th index, I can see that it logs the row and sequence (l_row and l_seq) count 3 times, in other words 1-3 for the records picked up in the second loop. I am beginning to think more and more that this is an oracle bug and I need to get oracles help to resolve it.

Comment: 0.05076 0.03757 
KL Debug: before LOOP
4 
1%
0.08832 0.03513 
KL Debug: in LOOP collection rowcount: 0
4 
1%
0.12345 0.03646 
KL Debug: in LOOP collection rowcount: 0
4 
1%
0.15991 0.03646 
KL Debug: in LOOP collection rowcount: 0
4 
1%
0.19638 0.03685 
KL Debug: in LOOP collection rowcount: 0
4 
1%
0.23322 5.00044 
KL Debug: in LOOP collection rowcount: 0

Comment: LOGS 1-2, without 3.

5.26972 0.03543 
KL Debug: in LOOP collection seq: 1
4 
1%
5.30515 0.00005 
KL Debug: in LOOP collection rowcount: 1
4 
0%
5.30520 0.00063 
KL Debug: in LOOP ename: School_1
4 
0%
5.30583 0.00012 
Collection - Getting collection ID for Collection Name: SITES
4 
0%
5.30595 0.03455 
Collection - Returning Collection ID 10267022417753 for Collection Name: SITES
4 
1%
5.34050 0.03472 
KL Debug: in LOOP collection seq: 2
4 
1%
5.37522 0.00007 
KL Debug: in LOOP collection rowcount: 2
4 
0%
5.37529 0.00057 
KL Debug: in LOOP ename: School_1

Comment: @Stefan I can only offer you tools to debug since I don't have access to your data. If you think it's a bug then pls create a reproducible case on apex.oracle.com