# Oracle Apex PLSQL Item not Updated with Cursor Variable

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a collection for my interactive grid that is created earlier with following details:

```
select c001,c002,c003 from emp_data;

Collection members are:
c001 = emp_id
c002 = dept_id
c003 = emp_code
```

For the IG i need to put a validation that would calculate the combination of emp_codes from emp_data table on the basis of department id and compare it with available set of emp_codes in the employee_data table.

The matched combination will be updated in :P1_COM_VALUE_FINAL table.
The loop, etc is working fine as the error returned is showing the correct department id when validation fails for each failed row.

The problem is: :P1_COM_VALUE_FINAL table is getting updated with same combination value irrespective of department id.
It is not updating as per loop.
So if for dept_id 1, combination is A-B-C
and for dept_id 2 combination is C-D-E
It updates with A-B-C twice.

The value of the page item is getting inserted in audit table and it is getting inserted as same value twice instead of different combinations.

I cannot post original code but i hope the logic intended is clear.
The only issue is page item not updating as per loop.

The page item session is set to Always replacing current value.

I tried setting page item as null just before the loop starts but that also did not help.

```
Declare
v_arranged VARCHAR2(1000) ;
v_available VARCHAR2(1000) ;
v_error varchar2(10000) :=null;


Cursor cur is
SELECT c001,c002,c003
LISTAGG(c003, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c003)
OVER (PARTITION BY c001) c003_combined
FROM apex_collections where collection_name='COLX'   and c001 = :EMP_ID and c002= :DEPT_ID;

 
Begin
FOR  crec in cur
  LOOP

 BEGIN
        select emp_arranged,emp_comb_avail into v_arranged,v_available
        from (
    select emp_arranged,emp_comb_avail,lengthb(emp_comb_avail)
    from (select (select listagg(emp_arranged ,'-') within group (order by emp_arranged) from (select regexp_substr(emp_comb_avail,'[^-]+', 1, level) emp_arranged
    from dual connect by regexp_substr(emp_comb_avail, '[^-]+', 1, level)
    is not null)) emp_arranged, emp_comb_avail
    from employee_data
 where department_id = crec.c002)
    where emp_arranged = crec.c003_combined);
 :P1_COM_VALUE_FINAL:= v_available;

    EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN

 v_error := 'Error with Department ID ||crec.c002';

  return v_error;
END;

END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; the expected output for that sample data; and an English explanation (not code) of the logic of how that sample data is to be processed to get the the expected output. At the moment, your question is very hard to follow and it is not clear where the error is or what you expect.

Comment: I'd suggest instrumenting that code block. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76332893/why-is-apex-collection-addmember-only-adding-the-last-index-called-of-the-outer/76335580#76335580) it has examples of how to use ```apex_debug```